# Create a static google map image with polygons from coordinates

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, static, polygon

Converting to a static map based on Google's API
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro

There is this url google give on make a static map image from url as an example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?path=color:0xff0000ff%7Cweight:5%7C40.737102,-73.990318%7C40.749825,-73.987963%7C40.752946,-73.987384%7C40.755823,-73.986397&size=512x512
```

As you see, each coordinate is separated by "%7C" which is a "|".

I have an array of coordinates (pulled from a form textfield) that creates a polygon within the google map js code: see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays

```
for (var i = 0; i < values["coords"].length; i++) {
var mycoords = values["coords"][i].lat + ", " + values["coords"][i].lng;

}
```

How can I merge array in order to use in static image url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming I can do something like this:

```js
var mergeCoords;
var gmapImgSrc;

for (var i = 0; i < values["coords"].length; i++) {
var mycoords = values["coords"][i].lat + ", " + values["coords"][i].lng;

}
        
mergeCoords = mycoords.join("%7C");
        
gmapImgSrc = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?path=color:0xff0000ff%7Cweight:5%7C" + mergeCoords + "&size=512x512";
```

Comment: Yes, this actually worked!